# how to pass value in xml for SOAP Request

Tags: c#, xml

I want to integrate this api but not understanding how and where the value can be pass in this XML for username and password.

```
 <xsd:element name="Login">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>

      </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:attribute name="UserName" use="required">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:length value="50"/>
          <xsd:minLength value="6"/>
          <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="Password" use="required">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:length value="255"/>
          <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
          <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:attribute>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The document main page is http://www.e-courier.com/ecourier/software/schema/xmloverview.html#Login . Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the XSD schema of the `Login` element. The schema describes how your request should look like.

On the page you linked see how the Login request in XML is shaped:

```
<Login UserName='test' Password='test' />
```

As that service is very picky on how the XML is shaped (it does matter for example how the namespace prefixes are named, which I assume is an implementation error on their part) I have used the XmlSerializer and matching DTO objects to get this working.

Notice how I add the XmlSerializerNamespaces and the prefixes that are required.

```
// setup the DTO
var s = new Envelope {
  Body = new Body {
     Login = new Login {
       UserName = "test" ,
       Password = "test" ,
       WebSite = "ecourier"
     }
  }
};

// setup namespaces and their prefixes    
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("SOAP", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
ns.Add("m","http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/");

// create the serializer
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // write the DTO to the MemoryStream
    ser.Serialize(ms, s, ns);

    using(var wc = new WebClient()) {
       wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
       var resp = wc.UploadData(
          "http://www.e-courier.com/ecourier/software/xml/XML.asp",
          ms.ToArray()
     );
     Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp));
    }
}
```

Here are the DTO classes to match the serialization structure for the XML payload:

```
[XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope {
    [XmlElement("Body", Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body {
    [XmlElement("Login", Namespace="http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/")]
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}

public class Login {
    [XmlAttribute("UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("WebSite")]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i have a question that i want to know the format of xsd is displaying in example and your answer is not matching.so what does meaning of the xsd why the company provide example like this so no one can understand how they will pass the value:)

Comment: The XSD describes the contract of the interface. Your Visual Studio (and other IDE's) can consume XSD's and show you if your xml is valid. The XSD is much richer in expressing validation rules then one example XMl fragment could express. And they do offer examples as well so i don't think it is too hard to translate from one into the other. Anyway, I have added how I've come to the login XElement based on the XSD.

Comment: i have post the xml and getting response `<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <Body>
  <Login UserName="test" Password="test" xmlns="http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/"/>
 </Body>
</Envelope>

Comment: @but as per document i will get <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> 
<SOAP:Body> 
<m:LoginResponse xmlns:m='http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/' UserGUID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000' /> 
</SOAP:Body> 
</SOAP:Envelope>   GUID of the User

Comment: Well, I don't know where you actually have to post that XML to. I only reversed engineered that url from their test webpage and was surprised it didn't break.

Comment: i am directly running the code from c# and i am currently hitting the url  `http://www.e-courier.com/ecourier/software/xml/xml.asp` the testing with username =test and pass = test . when i directly post the xml in postman this is running correctly and give us GUID but from C# this is not returning response as per document

Comment: the code is converting the xml <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <Login UserName="test" Password="test" xmlns="http://www.e-courier.com/software/schema/public/" />
  </Body>
</Envelope> and when i post this to `http://www.e-courier.com/ecourier/software/xml/XML.asp` response is same as c#  i am getting from postmen

Comment: I have switched to using the XML serializer as that server is very picky about how the prefixes are named. That is weird but I guess not much we can do about, This changed code does now throw a SOAPfault I hope due to me not providing valid credentials

Comment: for testing credentials is user -  test and password -  test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150401/discussion-between-rene-and-a-goutam).

Comment: i have a question can you please tell me how you design the ` DTO classes to match the serialization structure for the XML`  so i can implement the method for convert the another xml . Hope you will answer me